# Dynamics CRM Marketing list dynamic date condition

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm

I need to build a marketing list with date condition like so:

Month("End Date") = "This month" + 4

Basically, find records with End Date in 4 month

For example, if I pull the list on 6/12/17 - I will get all records with end date in Oct: 10/1/17, 10/2/17, etc

The closest I found is "Next X Month" but it also includes records within 3 month.

As an alternative - I'm exploring a path of creating workflow to update the "query" value of the marketing list record. Unfortunately, it's not possible to add Query field to the default form... this is getting very complex for a simple requirement.

Any ideas would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

In the marketing list manage members, use "Add using Advanced Find" option and add all records with "Next 4 Month". Then use "Remove using Advanced Find" option and remove all records with "Next 3 Months".

Comment: You are referring to a Static list... this won't work for me - I'm looking for a Dynamic list - something users won't need to touch once it's set up.

Answer (score 0):

Basically we can have a batch job every night, which will calculate the desired date or month filter for each contact record. Then fetchxml query for dynamic Marketing list can target this field.

Similarly rollup field can also be tried in contact.